# Vscode doesn't read default settings, every extension-setting is set as undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have freshly installed visual studio code via winget.
However it seems vscode doesn't read my *defaultSettings.json*, only the my current *settings.json*, which is empty, as it should.
Most settings are undefined and all settings for extensions are undefined.
When a extension is installed it has its default settings applied but after vscode restart/reload all of it is set as undefined.

### **Example.**

After installation of vscode, everything is fine. I install the extension *Powershell* by microsoft. Initially, when I look at the settings for the extension all default paths are there, default values are set and default checked check boxes are checked.
After a reload or restart, those default settings are now gone, except for some of the check boxes. Paths and values are now undefined.
If I look in *defaultSettings.json* those default settings are there but it seems they aren't read.

[Settings fresh extension install. Before reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSM6S.png)

[Settings after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE7V2.png)

The same problem applies to all extensions.

I have tried pressing *Reset Setting* on a setting and some check box values switches for a second. But nothing stays, nothing happens with paths and values.

---

This happen both at my desktop at work and at my home desktop.
This is on windows 11 and windows 10 respectively.
Vscode is installed in appdata.
I have checked if my user have permission to the folders and it does.

I have no idea what to do. I do not have much experience with vscode.
I have copied everything in the *defaultSettings.json* to my *settings.json* as a work-around, but it is not a pretty solution. It makes everything much less flexible, and gives extra work when installing new extensions.

```
Help: About

Version: 1.85.0 (user setup)
Commit: af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c
Date: 2023-12-06T20:48:09.019Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "_Most settings are undefined and all extensions settings are undefined_"? please elaborate about what you are observing. also, a screenshot in addition to that might help.

Comment: Added a example and some screenshots.

Comment: huh. this is indeed weird. can you show some related content from defaultSettings.json before and after reload (paste into code block)? or if they are they same before and after, no need to paste twice. And is this just for settings related to the PowerShell extension? or does it affect other extension settings and builtin VS Code settings as well?

Comment: As far as I know this applies to everything under Extensions in the settings tab.
Nothing changes in defaultSettings.json other than extensions add their defaults after installation, nothing changes after reload.

Comment: I suggest that you also raise a bug ticket, which you can do from the `Help > Raise Issue` menubar item in VS Code. If you do, please provide as much detail as you can about the issue and how to reproduce it there, and please ping me here with a link to it once it is created.

Comment: Here's the ticket: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200946)
I installed vscodium now, and that works without these issues.